# What makes a model change get propagated via JFace databinding?

Tags: java, data-binding, jface

In order to understand how JFace databindings is working, I have a model object with two properties. Changing one property should set the other to the same value:

```
public class Model {
  private double x;
  private double y;
  private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName,
            PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }   

    public void setX(double x) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("x", this.x, this.x = x);
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("y", y, this.y = y);
        setX(y);
    }

    public double y() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Now in a separate class I define two Text widgets, `xText` and `yText`, which are bound to this object like this:

```
    DataBindingContext bindingContext = new DataBindingContext();
    bindingContext.bindValue(WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify).observe(xText),
            BeanProperties.value(HumidityScanParameters.class,"x").observe(getModel()));
    bindingContext.bindValue(WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify).observe(yText),
            BeanProperties.value(HumidityScanParameters.class, "y").observe(getModel()));
```

I have found that if I change the text in `yText`, then the setter is automatically called as expected, and this sets both `y` and `x` in the model. However, *`xText` is not updated*. Why is this? Shouldn't the `firePropertyChange()` call arrange for the Text to be updated?

Thanks,
Graham.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler was optimising away the initial value of `this.x` and `this.y`, which led the `PropertyChangeSupport` instance to discard the change notification. It didn't think anything had changed. If I introduce a temporary variable like this:

```
public void setX(double x) {
    double oldValue = this.x;
    this.x = x;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("x", oldValue, x);
}
```

then the notifications occur as I might expect.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>I guess it's because you put `this.x` to your event before haveing it updated properly.</strike>

<strike>Try this:</strike>

<strike>public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;  // update the model!
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("x", this.x, x);
    }</strike>

(see comments ;-) )

Comment: Thanks @Andreas_D, my understanding is that the 2nd arg to firePropertyChange() is the _old_ value, and the 3rd is the _new_ value. Your version would send the new value twice...is that what's expected?

Comment: In fact, the documentation for `firePropertyChange()` says that no event will be fired if new and old values are equal and non-null, so your source definitely doesn't do what I need.

Comment: Ahh, obfuscated code, you did a field assignment in the third parameter and trapped me ;-) -- HEY, the (-1) is for the code in YOUR question! ;-)